# r scatter plot and regression line issues

Tags: r

I am trying to create to regression line for this graph, why is the below code not working?

After doing so, I need to create a custom legend with labels: black dot named 'actual' and blue dash (corresponding to the line) named 'predicted'

```
library(ggplot2)
d1 <- c(20,30,40,50,60,70)
d2 <- c(23, 32,41,53,60,69)

df <- data.frame(d1, d2)


ggplot(df,aes(x=d1,y=d2)) +
  geom_point(size=1.1)+
  geom_smooth(method = "glm", 
              method.args = list(family = "binomial"), 
              se = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the range of values for the dependent variable in the chart is not between 0 and 1, in `geom_smooth()` the family can't be binomial, as noted by the error message from `ggplot()`:

```
`geom_smooth()` using formula 'y ~ x'
Warning message:
Computation failed in `stat_smooth()`:
y values must be 0 <= y <= 1
```

If we use the default value for `family=`, the regression line prints.

```
library(ggplot2)
d1 <- c(20,30,40,50,60,70)
d2 <- c(23, 32,41,53,60,69)

df <- data.frame(d1, d2)


ggplot(df,aes(x=d1,y=d2)) +
     geom_point(size=1.1)+
     geom_smooth(method = "glm", 
                 se = FALSE)
```

[image]

One way to annotate the plot would be to add the regression line and R^2 information. We can do this with the `ggpubr` package and its `stat_regline_equation()` function.

```
library(ggpubr)
ggscatter(df, x = "d1", y = "d2", add = "reg.line",
          add.params = list(color = "blue", fill = "lightgray")) +
     stat_cor(label.x = 3, label.y = 70) +
     stat_regline_equation(label.x = 3, label.y = 66)
```

...and the output:

[image]

Comment: @Achilles - Legends are useful to distinguish subsets of the points on a chart based on the values of a third variable. In the data provided with your question there is no third variable, so it may be more useful to print the regression equation via the `ggpubr` package than to include another legend.